# Xamarin Forms - How can i pass the value of a variable to a another .cs?

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a reservation app , my problem is when I tapped "reserve"
I always get `null` JSON value just like this:

[image: Picture]

I don't think I wrote the code correctly that's why I have a problem I tried to do this things:

**Mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
public async void btnSignin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSignin.IsEnabled = false;
    bool valid = false;
    int name = 0;



    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://secret.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/users/view");
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(response);



    for ( int i = 0; i < user.Count; i++)
    {
        if( (entUser.Text == user[i].mem_acc_username) && (entPass.Text == user[i].mem_acc_password))
        {
                valid = true;
            name = i;

        }
    }

    bool v = valid;
    if (v == true)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Successfully Login", "Welcome Back " + user[name].mem_fname + " " + user[name].mem_lname, "OK");


        DReservation reserve = new DReservation(); // this is what i want to be passed in DineinReservation.cs i need the value of it


        reserve.mem_account_no = user[name].mem_account_no;
        reserve.mem_fname = user[name].mem_fname;
        reserve.mem_mobile_no = user[name].mem_mobile_no;

        await  Navigation.PushAsync(new DineinReservation);


        btnSignin.IsEnabled = true;


    }
    else
    {
        await   DisplayAlert("Failed", "Invalid Username or Password", "OK");
        btnSignin.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

**DineinReservation.xaml.cs**

And then I wrote this code that I think it will serve as to get the values of DReservation from Mainpage

```
private async Task btnReserve_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DReservation reserve = new DReservation();

    reserve.res_name = "Dine-in";
    reserve.res_num_of_persons = entNumber.Text;
    reserve.res_arrival_date = "test";
    reserve.res_arrival_time = temp;
    reserve.res_note = "none";
    reserve.custom_package = "none";

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reserve);

    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var result = await client.PostAsync("http://secret.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/reservation/insert_reservation", content);

    if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Success :",json, "OK");

    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Failed", json, "OK");
    }
}
```

**DReservation.cs**

```
public class DReservation
{

    public string mem_account_no { get; set; }
    public string res_name { get; set; }
    public string res_num_of_persons { get; set; }
    public string res_arrival_date { get; set; }
    public string res_arrival_time { get; set; }
    public string res_note { get; set; }
    public string mem_fname { get; set; }
    public string custom_package { get; set; }
    public string mem_mobile_no { get; set; }
}
```

**Users.cs**

```
public class Users
{
    public string mem_account_no { get; set; }
    public string mem_no { get; set; }
    public string mem_acc_username { get; set; }
    public string mem_acc_password { get; set; }
    public string mem_status { get; set; }
    public string mem_question { get; set; }
    public string mem_answer { get; set; }
    public string mem_fname { get; set; }
    public string mem_lname { get; set; }
    public string mem_address { get; set; }
    public string mem_date_applied { get; set; }
    public string mem_bday { get; set; }
    public string mem_mobile_no { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you please send the Json string ?

Comment: click the highlighted word "Picture"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ej8z.jpg

Comment: @PratiusDubey this is the json string

Comment: As, i'm looking you are sending two request to service, which service are not giving actual json. it's not mention.did you try on postman before sending from app. just try once on postman it giving same or not- https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: @PratiusDubey yes i tried it works perfectly my only problem is i can't get the mem_account_no from Users.cs which is foreign key to DReservation.cs , if you saw this code  reserve.mem_account_no = user[name].mem_account_no; i'm actually just converting it get the string from Users.cs to DReservation.cs or i written the code wrong

Comment: @PratiusDubey

Here's what i want to happen

[{"res_no":"1","mem_account_no":"1","res_name":"test","res_num_of_persons":"5","res_arrival_date":"2018-05-05","res_arrival_time":"00:00:00","res_note":"test","mem_fname":"jeremy","custom_package":"test","mem_mobile_no":"09129609612"}


and this what i always get

[{"res_no":"1","mem_account_no":"null","res_name":"test","res_num_of_persons":"5","res_arrival_date":"2018-05-05","res_arrival_time":"00:00:00","res_note":"test","mem_fname":"null","custom_package":"test","mem_mobile_no":"null"}

Comment: can you please give me some example on how you pass data to another xaml.cs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page are just C# classes - you pass variables the way you would with any C# class.  Namely, as an argument to the constructor, or using a public property or method.

```
DReservation reserve = new DReservation(); 

reserve.mem_account_no = user[name].mem_account_no;
reserve.mem_fname = user[name].mem_fname;
reserve.mem_mobile_no = user[name].mem_mobile_no;

await  Navigation.PushAsync(new DineinReservation(reserve));
```

then in DineinReservation.xaml.cs

```
public DineinReservation(DReservation reserve) {
   // reserve will contain the data passed from the main page
}
```

Comment: thank you! what if i don't want to PushAsync directly to DineinReservation? because there's more page before i can go there.

Comment: I would probably pass my data to B's constructor, then again to C's constructor

Comment: btw. how can you pass a constructor in master detail?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) for saving data across the app. If some values need to be used across the app I use this.

I find it very readable and clean than Constructors and Saving publically in App.cs

Comment: Thanks! i'll try this